# How to failover to new Master node when using Redis with Sentinel and redis-py?

Tags: python, redis, high-availability, failover, redis-py

To subscribe to Sentinel failover, what is the name of the Channel, and how do I detect that I need to refresh the master in the subscribed function?

I have a multi node Redis setup using Redis Sentinel for High Availability and failover.

I need to setup a Pub/Sub to Redis to detect when the Redis Master has failed and the system has elected a new Master.

```
_sentinel = redis.sentinel.Sentinel([(app.config["REDIS_HOSTNAME"],app.config["REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT"])])
_master = _sentinel.master_for(app.config["REDIS_SERVICE_NAME"])

def _sentinel_message_handler(message):
    #TODO how do I detect that there is a new Redis Master?

_pubsub = _master.pubsub()
_pubsub.subscribe(**{app.config["TODO"]:_sentinel_message_handler})
```

Comment: A list of channels can be found here: https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#pubsub-messages

Comment: I see one issue here is that the REDIS_HOSTNAME should be running through a list of Sentinel Hostnames trying each one successively until a connection is achieved.  This prevents crashing on startup just because one sentinel node is down.

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this, you will want to subscribe to the sentinel, not the master node.  The channel you are looking for is `"+switch-master"`. The Sentinel documentation indicates the channel as `"switch-master"` "without the +", but as of 3.2.4 the + is included.

[Redis Sentinel Pub/Sub Message Docs](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#pubsub-messages)

You should be able to reference the redis-py docs for the rest.
[Redis-py Docs](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#publish--subscribe)

---

**UPDATE**

You could also consider using the `client-reconfig-script` setting.

> When the master changed because of a failover a script can be called in
>   order to perform application-specific tasks to notify the clients that the
>   configuration has changed and the master is at a different address.

http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/sentinel.conf

Hope that helps

Comment: The sentinel object doesn't have a pubsub method.  Only the master.  I agree that this seems odd as I want the failover to work even if the master is unplugged.  Do I need to find all the slaves and pubsub to every slave as well as the master?

Comment: Well the primary issue is that the failover events are not published to the Redis nodes, only the Sentinels.  The only thing you will see in the Redis pub/sub are "__sentinel__:hello" events.

Comment: I am guessing you are wanting to listen for failovers so you can quickly reconfigure your client?  If sentinel pub/sub is out of the question, one idea would be to use: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/client.py#L414  as your source of truth.  Not ideal though.

Comment: I think what I want to do is the following,
1) Use Sentinel to find the Master node
2) Use the Master node to find all the slave nodes
3) Subscribe pub/sub for the master as well as the slave nodes.
Then when a new master is assigned, hopefully the message handler will be called.

Comment: Maybe this would work for you?  `http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/sentinel.conf`` Search for:  "CLIENTS RECONFIGURATION SCRIPT"